# How do I add an li element and then a child div element with text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm omitting the HTML because this is pretty simple code segment. I'm taking input from a text box and adding it to a list. For styling reasons I would like to put that text in a div inside li, but I'm having issues figuring out how to get that to work.

My code:

```
    var task = $("#new_task").val();
    if (task !== "") {
      var elem = $("<li class='task'></li>").text(task);
      $(elem).append("<button class='remove'>X</button>");
      $("#list").append(elem);
      $("#new_task").val("");
    }
```

My attempted solution:

```
    var task = $("#new_task").val();
    if (task !== "") {
      var elem = $("<li class='task'></li>");
      $(elem).append("<div></div>").text(task);
      $(elem).append("<button class='remove'>X</button>");
      $("#list").append(elem);
      $("#new_task").val("");
    }
```

The following line adds the div properly, but as soon as I do .text() the div doesn't even show up in the HTML anymore:

```
$(elem).append("<div></div>");
```

Comment: `$(elem).append(<div></div>);` is invalid Javascript. You must quote `<div></div>`.

Comment: @connexo My apologies, that was a typo on my end. The issue still exists though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append `<div>` tag with text easily using:

```
$(elem).append($('<div/>', { text: task }));
```

```js
$('#add').click(function() {
  var task = $("#new_task").val();
  if (task !== "") {
    var elem = $("<li class='task'></li>");
    $(elem).append($('<div/>', { text: task }));
    $(elem).append("<button class='remove'>X</button>");
    $("#list").append(elem);
    $("#new_task").val("");
  }
});
```

```css
li > div {background-color:skyblue;padding:4px 8px;margin:5px 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="new_task" /><br>
<button id="add">Add</button>
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Comment: Thank you. Would you be able to explain quickly why .text() wasn't working for div but did for li?

Comment: This happens because you had applied text() to a jquery object for li like `$("<li class='task'></li>").text(task);` but for div you were trying `$(elem).append("<div></div>").text(task);` but the div here is not a jquery object but a HTML string and text method can not be applied on string until the element is added to dom. I hope that make sense.